# How does modern android messaging apps work without foreground

Tags: android, background-service

As I know, in order to keep connection to the server in an android app (via sockets or polling) we need a foreground service with a permanent notification. But messengers like Telegram, WhatsApp or Facebook don't have one. That is why I wonder, how do they works? Do they use WorkManager in order to receive events from server and there is no sockets or polling?

Comment: Don't they receive a push notification?

Comment: They use Firebase Cloud Messaging (push notifications) or some alternative solution for this, like Amazon Simple Notification Service etc.